# Add animation to UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to animate an imageView with this CAAnimation so I added the following extension to UIImageView:

```
extension UIImageView {

var ovalPathSmall: UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 50.0, width: 0.0, height: 0.0))
}

var ovalPathLarge: UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 2.5, y: 17.5, width: 95.0, height: 95.0))
}

var ovalPathSquishVertical: UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 2.5, y: 20.0, width: 95.0, height: 90.0))
}

var ovalPathSquishHorizontal: UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 20.0, width: 90.0, height: 90.0))
}

func wobble() {
    let animationDuration: CFTimeInterval = 0.3
    // 1
    var wobbleAnimation1: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    wobbleAnimation1.fromValue = ovalPathLarge.CGPath
    wobbleAnimation1.toValue = ovalPathSquishVertical.CGPath
    wobbleAnimation1.beginTime = 0.0
    wobbleAnimation1.duration = animationDuration

    // 2
    var wobbleAnimation2: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    wobbleAnimation2.fromValue = ovalPathSquishVertical.CGPath
    wobbleAnimation2.toValue = ovalPathSquishHorizontal.CGPath
    wobbleAnimation2.beginTime = wobbleAnimation1.beginTime + wobbleAnimation1.duration
    wobbleAnimation2.duration = animationDuration

    // 3
    var wobbleAnimation3: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    wobbleAnimation3.fromValue = ovalPathSquishHorizontal.CGPath
    wobbleAnimation3.toValue = ovalPathSquishVertical.CGPath
    wobbleAnimation3.beginTime = wobbleAnimation2.beginTime + wobbleAnimation2.duration
    wobbleAnimation3.duration = animationDuration

    // 4
    var wobbleAnimation4: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    wobbleAnimation4.fromValue = ovalPathSquishVertical.CGPath
    wobbleAnimation4.toValue = ovalPathLarge.CGPath
    wobbleAnimation4.beginTime = wobbleAnimation3.beginTime + wobbleAnimation3.duration
    wobbleAnimation4.duration = animationDuration

    // 5
    var wobbleAnimationGroup: CAAnimationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    wobbleAnimationGroup.animations = [wobbleAnimation1, wobbleAnimation2, wobbleAnimation3,
        wobbleAnimation4]
    wobbleAnimationGroup.duration = wobbleAnimation4.beginTime + wobbleAnimation4.duration
    wobbleAnimationGroup.repeatCount = 2
    self.layer.addAnimation(wobbleAnimationGroup, forKey: nil)

}
```

then this to my viewDiLoad:

```
     NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target: self, selector: "x",
        userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func x() {
    questionIcon.wobble()
}
```

questionIcon is an outlet to the image I want to animate, but it doesn't move! What is wrong with the code? thanks

Answer (score 2):

It isn't at all clear what you are trying to do; your code as it stands is nonsense. You are making animation objects like this:

```
CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
```

But a UIImageView does not have a `path` property so you are not animating anything. The whole notion that a UIImageView might have an animatable `path` property is just something you made up in your head. You don't get to do that...

What you *are* allowed to do with a UIImageView is prepare a sequence of images (which you can create in code) and hand them to the image view to be played in sequence (as its `animationImages`) like the frames of a cartoon. Perhaps that is the direction you should be taking here.

Comment: For an example of making `animationImages` and playing them, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_uiimageview_and_uiimage_animation